# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "Foreign": syntax error (code 1):

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite

i getting this error  when i want to write some values in my database. Here is my error:
Error inserting Foreign=someValue Translation=someValue                                                                         android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "Foreign": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO TableDataBase(Foreign,Translation) VALUES (?,?)

My DBHelper.java :

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper implements BaseColumns { //Класс для работы с базой данных.

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mydatabase";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "TableDataBase";
public static final String FOREIGN_COLUMN = "Foreign";
public static final String TRANSLATION_COLUMN = "Translation";

private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_SCRIPT = "create table " //Скрипт создания база данных.
        + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + BaseColumns._ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "  + FOREIGN_COLUMN + " text not null, " + TRANSLATION_COLUMN + " text not null);";

DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

public DBHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, name, factory, version);
}

public DBHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version, DatabaseErrorHandler errorHandler) {
    super(context, name, factory, version, errorHandler);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {//Функция того, что происходит при создании БД.
    db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_SCRIPT);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) { //Функция того, что происходит при обновленнии версии БД.
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF IT EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE); //Удаляем старую таблицу и создаём новую.
    onCreate(db); //Создаём новую таблицу.
}
```

And where i want to insert value :

```
public void OnClickOk(View view) { //Действия при нажатии на "галочку".     ДОРАБОТАТЬ
    mDatabaseHelper = new DBHelper(this, "mydatabase", null, 1);
    SQLiteDatabase sdb = mDatabaseHelper.getWritableDatabase(); //Создание обьекта баззы данных для записи.
    ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues(); //Обьект в который будут записываться данные а потом сохраняться в БД.
    newValues.put("Foreign", foreign.getText().toString()); //Сохранение иностранного языка в обьект.
    newValues.put("Translation", translation.getText().toString()); //Сохранение перевода слова в обьект.
    sdb.insert("TableDataBase", null, newValues); //Сохранение данных в таблице.
}
```

Comment: Foreign keyword might be reserved.. Can you try changing the name of this column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FOREIGN` is a [sqlite keyword](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html). Either rename the column, or quote it as e.g. `"FOREIGN"`.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need put auto increment row in insert quert.

remove it, like this.

```
public void OnClickOk(View view) { //Действия при нажатии на "галочку".     ДОРАБОТАТЬ
mDatabaseHelper = new DBHelper(this, "mydatabase", null, 1);
SQLiteDatabase sdb = mDatabaseHelper.getWritableDatabase(); //Создание обьекта баззы данных для записи.
ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues(); //Обьект в который будут записываться данные а потом сохраняться в БД.
newValues.put("Translation", translation.getText().toString()); //Сохранение перевода слова в обьект.
sdb.insert("TableDataBase", null, newValues); //Сохранение данных в таблице.
```

}